# Unable to get value of aliased string type F#

Tags: f#

Trying to play around with some F# typing and having a hard time understanding how to get the string out of this

```
type EmailAddress = EmailAddress of string
type VerifiedEmail = VerifiedEmail of EmailAddress
type VerificationHash = VerificationHash of string
type VerificationService = (EmailAddress * VerificationHash) -> VerifiedEmail option
type EmailContactInfo =
    | Unverified of EmailAddress option
    | Verified of VerifiedEmail

let createEmailAddress (s : string) : EmailAddress option = 
    if Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$")
        then Some (EmailAddress s)
        else None

let createEmailInfo (email : string) : EmailContactInfo =
    match email with
    | s -> (Unverified (createEmailAddress s))

let getEmail (email : Entities.EmailContactInfo) : string =
    match email with
    | Entities.Verified s -> string s
    | Entities.Unverified s -> 
        match s with
        | Some s -> string s // *
        | None -> ""
```

I'm not sure how to change the `string s` call @ `// *` above to get the string here so that when I call:

```
    [<HttpGet("emailtest")>] 
    member __.GetEmail() : ActionResult<string> = 
        getEmail(Entities.createEmailInfo("dingo@gmail.com"))
        |> ActionResult<string>
```

I get "dingo@gmail.com" instead of 'EmailAddress "dingo@gmail.com"'

Comment: I'm not sure why you've decided to make VerifiedEmail an EmailAddress, which again is a string. And that's why you observe what you state, and you'd need to deconstruct to get the string. Instead I would probably just make VerifiedEmail a string directly, just as EmailAddress is.

Comment: It is code following a talk on DDD with F# that I was playing around with, I don't purport to be an expert on the why but the presenter makes some strong arguments for the typing.

Comment: Right, it's usable for demonstrating certain techniques, using strong typing. It's just that putting the string in an EmailAddress, and then putting that in a VerifiedEmail, doesn't serve any purpose that I can see. It's like putting your white socks in a drawer within a drawer, instead of just having a normal drawer for your white socks. The author of that piece of code may have been influenced by object oriented programming, where you'd perhaps inherit VerifiedEmail from EmailAddress - but that doesn't translate well to DUs in F#.

Comment: The author is a former OO programmer, Scott Wlaschin. The purpose of it is to understand the domain modeling, not so much the primitive type beneath it. DDD people would probably argue it is more for humans than compilers. ```Unverified of EmailAddress option``` even a client can read and confirm requirements.

Comment: Scott Wlaschin certainly knows what he's doing - he taught me real F# through his site - so I guess there's some purpose that's not visible in the snippet. That's quite allright.

Comment: This is the talk on domain modeling made functional https://youtu.be/2JB1_e5wZmU

Answer (score 2):

You need to deconstruct EmailAddress object and you can also combine it with outer match-with expression, so something like following should work for you:

```
let getEmail (email : Entities.EmailContactInfo) : string =
    match email with
    | Entities.Verified s -> string s
    | Entities.Unverified None -> ""
    | Entities.Unverified (Some (EmailAddress s)) -> s
```